# How to change the icon for a sphinx-generated page?

Tags: css, python-sphinx

I would like my sphinx-generated web page to have a particular icon.
In my other web pages i have the line

```
<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='http://aim-bigfoot.uzh.ch/~docs/path/to/icon/favicon.png' />
```

inside the `<head>` tag.

Is there a way to modify a template or a config file to have this line inserted in the resulting html file?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem.

In conf.py you can set the entry `html_favicon`.

In my case I set:

```
html_favicon = `http://aim-bigfoot.uzh.ch/~docs/path/to/icon/favicon.png'
```

Now the generated page has the specified icon.

Comment: I can't find a reference to [`html_fsvicon` in the documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/search.html?q=html_fsvicon). So I don't understand how declaring a Python variable in the `conf.py` links to the `<head>` tag in the generated HTMLs...

Comment: The option is called `html_favicon`: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_favicon